# Surface mounted electrolytic capacitor markings

Tags: identification, electrolytic-capacitor

Is this 22 µF / 16V? General rule of thumb for these markings?

[image]

Comment: 220µF/16V is more likely given its size.

Comment: Probably 220uF, traditionally electrolytics had enough surface area to print the value without using the last digit as an exponent. (yes, 16V)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this document](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDE0000/DME0000COL92.pdf) from Panasonic, page 11.

[image]

Comment: This does vary by vendor though. Like [this one](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=CKke1CSX&id=EE62AF50500E10CBD01A2F7C54508D79913CD557&thid=OIP.CKke1CSX0kQ1y7WxZ1b6QwHaJG&q=220uf+16V+SMT+capacitor&simid=608006507441752368&selectedIndex=88&ajaxhist=0)