# What is the value of this SMD capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I am not an electrical engineer.  I can sometimes solder SMD components that I know are bad.

Can anyone tell me the value of this capacitor?

[image]

Comment: For sure 10µF. But I'm not sure about the voltage retaining 35V I guess.

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/500183/2028 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/546098/2028

Comment: Is there a manufacturer logo or something on the side? They might have the markings documented somewhere.

Comment: Another related (just linking these together for reference): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/352110/2028

Comment: I posted a compilation question and answer which may be useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/700710/2028